# Webpage Jumps on Javascript Tab Click

Tags: javascript, tabs

I'm having an issue with some Javascript I used to make a box with tabs.

The issue is that every time I click on a different tab the webpage makes a large jump up for seemingly no reason.  It is not hitting the bottom of the webpage when content shrinks between clicks as far as I can tell.

Can anyone provide a little help on where the code might be going wrong?

Also, is it possible to make the clickable tabs images?  When I try to us an img tag it breaks the code for me...

Thank you!

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var activeTabIndex = -1;
var tabNames = ["tab1","tab2","tab3"];

$(".tab-menu > li").click(function(e){
    for(var i=0;i<tabNames.length;i++) {
        if(e.target.id == tabNames[i]) {
            activeTabIndex = i;
        } else {
            $("#"+tabNames[i]).removeClass("active");
            $("#"+tabNames[i]+"-tab").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
    $("#"+tabNames[activeTabIndex]+"-tab").fadeIn();
    $("#"+tabNames[activeTabIndex]).addClass("active");
    return false;
});
});
```

CSS (if needed):

```
body{
        background: #fff;
        margin:0;
        }
        .clear{
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        }
        a {
        text-decoration: none;
        }
        #tab-container{
        font-family: Arial,  Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height:16px;
        margin: auto;
        width: 700px;
        border:0px solid #ccc;
        background:#e1eff8;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:13px;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -15px 2px #dadada;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset  0 -20px 2px #dadada;
        box-shadow: inset 0-5px 10px #dadada;
        border-top-left-radius:10px;
        border-top-right-radius:10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
        }
        #tab-container ul{
        list-style: none;
        width: 100%;
        }
        #tab-container ul.tab-menu li{
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        background: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #ddc;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-width: 1px;
        color: #999;
        cursor: default;
        height: 14px;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        }
        #tab-container ul.tab-menu li.active{
        background: #fff;
        color: #0088CC;
        height: 15px;
        border-bottom: 0;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, white 10%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 10%, from(#ebebeb), to(white));
        }
        .tab-top-border {
        border-bottom: 0px solid #d0ccc9;
        }
        .tab-content{
        margin:  auto;
        background: #efefef;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ddc;
        border-top-style: none;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        font-size: 13px;
        display: none;
        height: auto;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 2px #dadada;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset  0 -2px 2px #dadada;
        border-top-left-radius:10px;
        border-top-right-radius:10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
        }
        #tab-container div.active{
        display: block;
        }
        .tab-content h1{
        line-height: 1em;
        height: 28px;
        font-size: 22px;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<br>
    <img alt="TIGER Grant - Web Header.jpg" style="" src="/images/pages/N757/TIGER%20Grant%20-%20Web%20Header.jpg"><br>
    <br>
    <p>Each year, the area welcomes over 5.7 million visitors to the sugar whites sands and emerald waters along its beaches.  The recognizes the importance of a clean, healthy environment to our economy and way of life.  In an effort to protect our natural resources, the  has launched  to develop, enhance, and promote projects and initiatives aimed at raising environmental awareness, reducing waste, increasing livability, and improving sustainability in the community.<br>
    <br>
    <span class="Subhead2">Program Overview</span></p>
    <img alt="TIGER Grant" style="width: 300px; height: 210px; float: right;" src="http://www.blank.gov/images/pages/N757/TIGER%20Web%20Logo.jpg">
    <p>Green Up is an education-based environmental awareness campaign designed to reach the residents of and visitors to.&nbsp; The program will seek to address environmental concerns and issues that affect the region by disseminating critical information via signage, special events, website/social media, news releases, and other promotional methods to the public.&nbsp; </p>
    <p>Green Up will advance the Core Values identified within the  including:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>We protect and enhance the quality of life for our residents, visitors, and retirees.</li>
        <li>We protect and preserve our unique natural resources.</li>
        <li>We embed sustainability into the fabric of the community.</li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <div id="tab-container">
    <ul class="tab-menu">
        <li id="tab1" class="active">Project Benefits</li>
        <li id="tab2">Project Support</li>
        <li id="tab3">Project Documents</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="tab-top-border"></div>
    <div id="tab1-tab" class="tab-content active">
    <p> </p>
    <li> Provide bicycle and pedestrian access throughout the District and across the Waterway.</li>
    <li> Provide needed vehicular, bicycle, and pedestrian access.</li>
    <li> Improvements will promote investment, economic development, and job creation throughout area.</li>
    <li> Proposed improvements to provide additional evacuation route connectivity to improve evacuation time during natural disasters.</li>
    <li> Economic development within will create a sustainable and vibrant economic center that is resilient and will withstand the natural and man-made disasters that occur along.</li>
    <p><br />
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2-tab" class="tab-content">
    <p>Project has generated tremendous support from many in our local community to our statewide partners and even from our leadership in Washington D.C.<br>
    <br>
    <span class="Subhead2">Federal Support</span></p>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Congressman</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Senate</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Senate</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="Subhead2"><br>
    State Support</span><br>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Governor</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Foundation</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Transportation</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Lieutenant</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_self" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Representative</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Senator</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="Subhead2"><br>
    Local Support</span><br>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Commission</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Blank</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Project</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Center</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Blank</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Farms</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Tourism</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">County</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Blank</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Blank</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Chamber</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">House</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Probate</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Blank</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p><br />
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3-tab" class="tab-content">
    <p>
    <span class="Subhead2">Project</span></p>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/"><span class="Hyperlink">Project<br>
        </span></a></li>
        <li><span class="Hyperlink"><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Project</a><br>
        </span></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/"><span class="Hyperlink">Analysis<br>
        </span></a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/"><span class="Hyperlink">Certification<br>
        </span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="Subhead2"><br>
    Supporting Documents</span><br>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/"><span class="Hyperlink">Plan<br>
        </span></a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/"><span class="Hyperlink">Blank<br>
        </span></a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Plan</a></li>
        <li><a class="Hyperlink" target="_blank" href="/DocumentCenter/View/">Sustainability</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p><br />
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I need to see your HTML to answer this, but I suspect I know the cause!

Comment: I can't replicate your issue; I tried making a jsFiddle but it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/buf03ct6/

Comment: I had to remove `display:none` in your `.tab-content` CSS to get it to work, mind

Comment: Awesome, it does seem to be working correctly there, ie. no jumping issues, but without the display:none in the .tab-content the page loads with all tabs stacked on top of each other until you start clicking specific tabs, which only loads the clicked tab.

Comment: I've added `style='display:none'` to tab2-tab and tab3-tab: https://jsfiddle.net/buf03ct6/2/